# Delete record based on text found in a field (

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I normally do most of this work in Excel 2007, but I do not think excel is the right tool for managing the data that I need to process. So I am trying to convert an excel spreadsheet to an Access 2007 db which I can do with no problem, but before doing anything to the spreadsheet I go through the process of cleaning up the data in it in order to use the resulting information. In excel I use a macro such as the following

```
Sub deletedExceptions_row()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo whoa

    Set ws = Sheets("data") 

    With ws
        For i = .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 3) = "" Or _
              VBA.Left(.Cells(i, 3), 4) = "511-" Or _
              VBA.Left(.Cells(i, 3), 5) = "CARL-" Then
                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    Exit Sub
whoa:
    MsgBox "Value of i is " & i
End Sub
```

to remove unnecessary records in the spreadsheet how would I accomplish the same thing in Access 2007.

The macro is looking for particular parts or rather the first few characters of the record's 3rd field in order to determine if the whole record needs to be removed (ex. 511-QWTY-SVP or CARL-52589-00). In all there about 180 such character types that affect 1000's of rows that need to be removed from the spreadsheet, but I would like to replicate that same process in Access 2007, but do not know how.

Thank you **all** for your assistance with this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Access you can execute a `DELETE` statement to discard rows where the value in a field is an empty string ("") or matches one of your patterns.

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE
       YourField = ""
    OR YourField ALike "511-%"
    OR YourField ALike "CARL-%";
```

With `YourField` indexed, that pattern matching in the WHERE clause offers a potentially large performance improvement over a query using the `Left()` function such as your spreadsheet macro used.  IOW, the following query would require the db engine to run those Left() expressions on every row of `YourTable`.  But with the query above and `YourField` indexed, the db engine could simply select the matching rows ... which can easily be an order of magnitude faster.

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE
       YourField = ""
    OR Left(YourField, 4) = "511-"
    OR Left(YourField, 5) = "CARL-";
```

Comment: when I try the following with all the text that access is supposed to find I get Query is too complex

Comment: If you mean you have 180 such matches, distribute them between multiple queries ... each of which includes a reasonable number of matches.  You would then need to execute each DELETE statement separately.  Alternately, if it's worth the effort to you, you could create a VBA procedure to do your deletions.

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub DeleteRows(strVal as string)
     strVal = Trim(strVal)
     if strVal = "" then exit sub
     dim dbs as Database
     set dbs = CurrentDB
     dbs.execute "Delete * FROM YOURTABLE where YOURFIELD Like '" & strVal & "*'"
     set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```

then call it for each item

```
DeleteRows("Carl-")
DeleteRows("511-")
```

Comment: Once you have a pattern in a table, there is no need for VBA as long as the "problem" is always the same.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have 180 possible problem rows, it may make sense to create a problem list table. For example:

**ExcelImport**

```
ID  ARow
1   Carl-abdre
2   511-ferw2
3   wywr-carl
4   123-456
```

**ProblemList**

```
Problem
511-
Carl-
```

**Query**

```
DELETE 
FROM ExcelImport
WHERE ExcelImport.ID In (
    SELECT ID 
    FROM ExcelImport, ProblemList 
    WHERE ARow Like [Problem] & "*" Or ARow & ""="")
```

**ExcelImport after query**

```
ID  ARow
3   wywr-carl
4   123-456
```

Comment: how would I add one? I assume you are referring to when I am setting up the table for access during the import I would assign a unique ID then. But does this work the same if the file is a .csv file because that is how I usually export from Excel

Comment: An alternative is to add a "to be deleted" field and update, rather than delete. A subquery would not be required, so no unique ID.

Comment: Pardon me in advance for asking the questions, but this all new to me. So during the import of the csv file that contains headers already, add a field that says "to be deleted" and let Access add primary key to the table. But how do I tell Access what the problems will be with the table? And how do I create the problem list?

Comment: @capnhud You have run into two ideas. You can add to be deleted, or an autonumber ID (import will do this for you), there is no need to do both, unless you would like to check before your final delete. Do not forget, you can import into an existing table.

Comment: You create the problem list from your knowledge of the problems. It is just a table with one field.

Comment: well I would definitely like to double check. Would I take all the values that I am concerned about and create a table for them. There are 180 different criteria that affect 1000's of rows

Comment: Yes, that would be the general idea. Once you have a table, it is easy to add or delete problems. You can also add a position field to problem, is you want to get fancy :) so you have "WHERE Position='LEFT STRING'"

Answer (score 0):

You manage database data using the SQL language. For Access, check:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177896%28v=office.12%29.aspx

```
Sub DeleteX()

    Dim dbs As Database, rst As Recordset
    Set dbs = OpenDatabase("Northwind.mdb")

    dbs.Execute "DELETE * FROM " _
        & "Employees WHERE Title ALike 'FOOBAR-%';"
    dbs.Close
End Sub
```